# jQuery selectors question

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

What's the difference in doing:

```
$(this).find('.action')
```

or

```
$('.action', this)
```

performance? if so which one is better and why?

something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has no difference per jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

Comment: Wouldn't it be better then to use `.find()` to prevent an extra call?

Comment: That extra call is just a reference to the actual function. It won't even affect the site performance as it will happen in fraction of milliseconds. But if you really want to care about that kind of micro performance management (which I don't think you should) then yes, it would be faster in terms of the number of machine instructions in order to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I know I don't have to worry about (micro-)performance with the extra call. Just curious :)